# Is there a easy way to have a substring of a utf8 encode string, the substring's repr's length less than N in python

Tags: python, algorithm, utf-8, substring, repr

for example i have a string, I hope find a easy way to get a substring, which encode in utf-8, and the length of the repr of the substring is <= N, of course i can try N/3 substring and increase N/3+1, N/3+2,...,but if there is a easy way?

```
word = u"this is a ship, and some other words".encode("utf-8")
#some way got a substring
substring = func(word, N)
#assert len(repr(substring)) <= N
```

Thanks!

Comment: do you care if it ends in the middle of a word, user-perceived character, Unicode codepoint?

Comment: For the first 128 UTF-8 characters, such as those in your example, one byte is one code point.  Do you want to have to deal with larger code points; two bytes and above?  Do you know how to distinguish them in the byte stream?

Comment: Binary search would certainly be better than doing +1 each time.

Comment: yes, the algorithm need process larger code points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach:

1. Take first N-1 bytes of the repr of the whole string.
2. Examine last 3 bytes to see if you broke an escape sequence and cut of bytes if necessary
3. Append a quote, keeping in mind that it may be `'` or `"`.
4. Eval the repr back to utf-8.
5. Examine the last few bytes to see if you broke the string in the middle of a Unicode code point and cut out bytes if necessary. You can tell apart leading bytes and continuation bytes by examining the bit pattern.